# Обновление блока div без перезагрузки страницы по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: ajax, php

здравствуйте, мне нужно сделать обновление блока div без перезагрузки страницы по нажатию на кнопку, этот блог содержит в себе информацию из базы mysql. подскажите пожалуйста как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a onclick="fync();">Текст ссылки</a>
<div id="block"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fync() {
$("#block").load("file.php", function() {
});
}; 
</script>
```

Comment: а если подгружаться должна отдельная функция в каком-то файле а не файл как в этом примере??

Comment: @privetsh, ajax запрашивает результат работы скрипта, то есть готовый html. Если хотите вызвать конкретную функцию из файла, то надо придумать как об этом оповестить сам php на сервере. Может передать get или post параметр с названием функции.

Кстати, код выше работает на библиотеке JQuery, о чем забыл упомянуть отвечающий: http://jquery-docs.ru/Ajax/

Comment: @Alex Krass `Ajax` может получить в ответ `Json` объект, и в этом случае провести определенные действия